# TFS 2013 Web Deploy and web API help pages

Tags: asp.net-web-api, tfs, web-deployment, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am using Team Foundation Server 2013 and have the nightly build configured to deploy a web application. The web application is making use of the web API help pages which depend on the built in XML documentation files.

I currently have these XML files being output to the App_Data folder. These are not being copied to the server during deployment. I tried checking in the documentation files but when the build process tried to regenerate them it caused an access error as the files are read-only.

I currently have a placeholder text file inside the App_Data folder included in the project to ensure that the folder gets created but I have to manually copy across the documentation files in order for the help pages to work as intended.

What is the correct/best way of forcing these files to be copied?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the project build order has the docs being built first. Right click on the solution and choose `Project Build Order`

[image: Project Build Order option after Solution right click]

[image: Dependencies tab on the Project Dependencies window]

[image: Build Order tab on the Project Dependencies window]

Then add some MSBuild logic in your pubxml or wpp.targets file to add the generated help files to the `FilesForPackagingFromProject` ItemGroup.

http://sedodream.com/2012/10/09/VSWebPublishHowToIncludeFilesOutsideOfTheProjectToBePublished.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Open the solution, right click on the .xml file, click Properties, for 'Copy to Output Directory' select 'Copy Always'.